# Accessing Returned value from MySQL Stored Procedure in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure that has 2 parameters, the first one is the cartId(which is the IN) and I have the newOrderId(which is the OUT). Now,
I know that the inCartId is the cart id which will come from the form or whatever means the cart is been access but I don't understand the OUT 
newOrderId since that is what MySQL will return. 
Now, in the PHP calling this Stored procedure, it will look like this.

```
$sql = 'CALL create_order(:cart_id, "What will be here")// The cart_id is what PHP will pass to MySQL, but what will be passed
    to the 2nd argument since PHP does not know before hand what MySQL will return.
```

````
CREATE PROCEDURE create_order(
    IN inCartId int,
    OUT newOrderId int
)
BEGIN

    -- Insert a new record into orders and obtain the new order ID
    INSERT INTO orders (created_on) VALUES (NOW());

    -- Obtain the new Order ID
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO newOrderId;

    -- Insert order details in order_detail table
    INSERT INTO order_detail (
        order_id, product_id, attributes, product_name, quantity, unit_cost
    )
    SELECT
        orderId,
        p.id,
        sc.attributes,
        p.name,
        sc.quantity,
        COALESCE( NULLIF( p.discounted_price, 0 ), p.price ) AS unit_cost
    FROM
        shopping_cart sc
        INNER JOIN products p ON sc.product_id = p.id
    WHERE
        sc.cart_id = inCartId
        AND
        sc.buy_now;

    -- Save the order's total amount
    UPDATE
        orders
    SET
        total_amount = (
            SELECT
                SUM( unit_cost * quantity )
            FROM
                order_detail
            WHERE
                order_id = orderId
        )
    WHERE
        id = orderId;

    -- Clear the shopping cart
    CALL shopping_cart_empty(inCartId);

END```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have been able to solve it. And this is how I did it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `shopping_cart_create_order2`(IN `inCartId` INT(11), OUT `newOrderId` INT(11)) BEGIN
    DECLARE newOrder int;
    -- Insert a new record into orders and obtain the new order ID
    INSERT INTO orders (created_on) VALUES (NOW());

    -- Obtain the new Order ID
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO newOrder;

    -- Insert order details in order_detail table
    INSERT INTO order_detail (
        order_id, product_id, attributes, product_name, quantity, unit_cost
    )
    SELECT
        newOrder,
        p.id,
        sc.attributes,
        p.name,
        sc.quantity,
        COALESCE( NULLIF( p.discounted_price, 0 ), p.price ) AS unit_cost
    FROM
        shopping_cart sc
        INNER JOIN products p ON sc.product_id = p.id
    WHERE
        sc.cart_id = inCartId
        AND
        sc.buy_now;

    -- Save the order's total amount
    UPDATE
     orders
    SET
        total_amount = (
            SELECT
                SUM( unit_cost * quantity )
            FROM
                order_detail
            WHERE
                order_id = newOrder
        )
    WHERE
        id = newOrder;

    -- Clear the shopping cart
    CALL shopping_cart_empty(inCartId);
    SET newOrder = newOrderId;
END
```

At PHP level// Probably at the Model/Entity level
First, we need to execute the

> shopping_cart_create_order2()

stored procedure. Which might probably be in a function.

Second, to get the last order id, we need to query it from the variable

> @oid

. It is important that we must call the method

> closeCursor()

of the PDOStatement  object in order to execute the next SQL statement.

```
function query($pdo, $sql, $parameters = []){
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($parameters);
    return $query;
}

function create_order($pdo, $cart_id){
    // Binding the parameters
    $parameters = [':cart_id' => $cart_id];

    // calling stored procedure command
    $sql = 'CALL shopping_cart_create_order2(:cart_id)';

    // prepare for execution of the stored procedure, pass value to the command 
    and execute the Stored Procedure
    $query = query($pdo, $sql, $parameters);

   // Then close Cursor. It is important for you to close it.
    $query->closeCursor();

   // execute the second query to get last insert id
    $row = $pdo->query("SELECT @oid AS oid")->fetch();
    return $row;    
}
```

For more info, see [enter link description here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-calling-mysql-stored-procedures/)

I hope am able to help someone out there who might probably fall into what I passed through.